# Can't get camelCase properties with latest Reinforced.Typings

Tags: reinforced-typings

I've just updated to latest (1.4.91) and everything is broken when it comes to camelCasing of properties :(

Unfortunately there don't seem to be any breaking changes in the release, but I suspect there were major changes to how this aspect is setup. We were using the standard Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml before, I see there's a new TsGlobal but even setting that doesn't seem to help.

#### Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    <RtTargetFile>$(ProjectDir)\Scripts\typings\css\CS.Interfaces.ts</RtTargetFile>
    <RtConfigurationMethod></RtConfigurationMethod>
    <RtWriteWarningComment>true</RtWriteWarningComment>
    <RtExportPureTypings>false</RtExportPureTypings>
    <RtDivideTypesAmongFiles>false</RtDivideTypesAmongFiles>
    <RtTargetDirectory>$(ProjectDir)Scripts\MyApplication</RtTargetDirectory>
    <RtRootNamespace>CabMD</RtRootNamespace>
    <RtBypassTypeScriptCompilation>false</RtBypassTypeScriptCompilation>
    <RtCamelCaseForMethods>false</RtCamelCaseForMethods>
    <RtCamelCaseForProperties>true</RtCamelCaseForProperties>
    <RtGenerateDocumentation>true</RtGenerateDocumentation>
    <RtDisable>false</RtDisable>        
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<RtAdditionalAssembly Include="CabMD.Schedule.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

#### Assembly

```
<Assembly: TsGlobal(CamelCaseForMethods:=False, CamelCaseForProperties:=True, RootNamespace:="CabMD", GenerateDocumentation:=True)>
```

#### Class

```
<TsInterface(Namespace:="CabMD.Models.WebAPI.Response")>
Public Class MasterNumberResult
        <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="code")>
        Public Property Code As String

        <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="fullName")>
        Public Property FullName As String

        <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="category")>
        Public Property Category As String

        <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="name")>
        Public Property Name As String

        <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="shortName")>
        Public Property ShortName As String
End Class
```

#### Generated Typing

```
export interface IMasterNumberResult
{
    Code: string;
    FullName: string;
    Category: string;
    Name: string;
    ShortName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to investigate this error with RT unit tests, but have found that everything works as expected.

What assembly contains your `<Assembly: TsGlobal>` attribtue? It has to be located within the same assembly, containing your `MasterNumberResult` class.

Comment: The same assembly, works fine in 1.2.4 now that I've reverted back (obviously commenting out those TsGlobal lines since that came later). The only change I made was updating the library.